# S3 REST API Get Object example

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We are trying to write an integration that will download a PDF via the s3 REST API. The documentation on using the [REST API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html) feels a bit lacking to me. I have done my best to recreate the examples in JAVA to no avail and was wondering if anybody knows of examples in java or other?

**MY EXAMPLE**
public class main {

```
private static final String AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "us-west-2";
private static final String AWS_S3_SERVICE_NAME = "s3";
private static final String AWS_S3_KEY_ID = "<My Key ID>";
private static final String AWS_S3_KEY_SECRET = "<My secret>";
private static final String BUCKET_NAME = "<My Bucket Name>";
private static final String DOCUMENT_OBJECT_KEY = "MyTest1.txt";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z").format(new java.util.Date());
    Response response = null;
    byte[] signatureKey = null;
    try {
        signatureKey = getSignatureKey(AWS_S3_KEY_ID, timeStamp, "us-west-2", "s3");
        response = getRestFileFromS3(timeStamp, IOUtils.toString(signatureKey, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(response.getHeaders());
}

static byte[] HmacSHA256(String data, byte[] key) throws Exception  {
    String algorithm="HmacSHA256";
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
    mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(key, algorithm));
    return mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF8"));
}

static byte[] getSignatureKey(String key, String dateStamp, String regionName, String serviceName) throws Exception  {
    byte[] kSecret = ("AWS4" + key).getBytes("UTF8");
    byte[] kDate    = HmacSHA256(dateStamp, kSecret);
    byte[] kRegion  = HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
    byte[] kService = HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
    byte[] kSigning = HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);
    return kSigning;
}

static Response getRestFileFromS3(String date, String signatureKey) {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient( new ClientConfig().register( LoggingFilter.class ) );

    WebTarget webTarget = client.target("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/")
            .path(BUCKET_NAME)
            .path(DOCUMENT_OBJECT_KEY);

    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder =  webTarget
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .header("Host", BUCKET_NAME+".s3.amazonaws.com")
            .header("Date", date)
            .header("Authorization", signatureKey);
    return invocationBuilder.get();
}
```

}

Comment: Any reason you aren't using the AWS SDK for Java?

Comment: Very long and boring story but yes, we have to try to get this to work w/o the SDK. If it's not possible, I can choose a different route. But, it appears it *should* work.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with doing it this way.  I use all my own hand-written AWS libraries.  I'm not a Java person but looking over your code to the best of my ability, it seems you've skipped over quite a bit.  You appear to be sort of just stringifying the signing key and setting the `Authorization:` header to that value.  You have to construct the canonical request and use that signing key to create the signature and concatenate the parts of the Authorization header. I don't see all of these things.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-auth-using-authorization-header.html

Comment: @BertAlfred Could you tell me which library are you using to create `Client` and make the request?